# Has a Scriptural index been compiled on Radak's 'Michlul'?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, rishonim, books-generally

While not in a current position to browse the the end of any modern printings of Michlul, I have been interested to know if any of them contain indices which enable easy searching for any verse mentioned throughout his manual.

Comment: If you download a pdf, it should be searchable using Ctrl-F. I use it on non-indexed pdfs I got from Hebrewbooks.org

Answer (score 4):

A question like this cannot be answered with 100% certainty, being that it is not truly possible in this day and age to know about every single sefer being published and republished, being that – to my knowledge (I would love to hear that I’m wrong) – there is no central organization/forum where all Jewish books post the details of their new publication/reprint. (The Library Of Congress does not take an ISBN for nor keep track of every book published in the U.S, contrary to popular belief.)

Nonetheless, there are places to look for such things. After ***thoroughly*** checking many such places (namely: Eichler's, Judaica Place, ZBerman Books, Zolsefer, the Otzar Hachochma, Hebrew books, Shabsi’s Judaica - a local seforim store in Baltimore which attracts people from the tri-state area because of the size of its collection), **I can say with a 95% confidence level that one has not been compiled**. In fact, I was hard pressed to even find a printing of a "Michlul" newer than 1842 (indeed, I failed)! Not even the Otzar Hachochma has one newer than that! I then began searching for the individual seforim of ספר השרשים and ספר הדקדוק. The newest one I found for ספר השרשים was the Berlin 1847 print, which had a 5-page index: [image: Page 1], [image: Page 2] [image: Page 3][image: Page 4][image: Page 5]
The Otzar did not have a single print of an individual ספר הדקדוק.
There is a ויקיטקסט currently going for the machlul (https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C_(%D7%A8%D7%93%22%D7%A7)) which even has hyperlinks for the pesukim to their respective ויקיטקסט entries, though it is still unfinished (new contributors are always welcomed).
On zberman books there was this one: https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%93%22%D7%A7, but it was out of stock, didn’t have a picture, and didn’t have edition information, so there is no telling there.

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed, I enjoy traveling to Shabsi's from time to time!

Comment: I even asked the "seforim guy" if he knew of any other editions, and he said that he thought the only edition was "the old red one". I think he was referring to the sefer hashorashim. Have you seen it?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel You will mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: First I'll pass on the 500 smackers, but yes probably.

Comment: No, I haven't, thanks for the great post.

Answer (score 2):

In William Chomshky's translation(1952) he provides an index,but is limited to chapter six which discusses syntactical remarks.

Sample page:

[image]

Comment: This index contains more pages,if you are interested let me know and will post them

Answer (score 1):

There is a new edition in preparation from מכון שלמה אומן. Additionally a compilation of ספרי השרשים is in in preparation see the seforim chatter [podcast episode](https://seforimchatter.buzzsprout.com/1218638/6226087-with-rabbi-reuven-chaim-klein-discussing-his-book-god-versus-gods-judaism-in-the-age-of-idolatry) with Rabbi Reuven Klein at around 50 minutes.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!